# PHP preg_match function variable extraction

Tags: php, regex, tags, pattern-matching, preg-match

Assuming that I have a string like this:

```
[$IMAGE[file_name|width|height]]
```

How can I match and obtain 2 variables

```
$tag = "IMAGE"
$param = "file_name|width|height"
```

Using a php preg_match function?

Answer (score 6):

```
$string = '[$IMAGE[file_name|width|height]]';
// Matches only uppercase & underscore in the first component
// Matches lowercase, underscore, pipe in second component
$pattern = '/\[\$([A-Z_]+)\[([a-z_|]+)\]\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "[$IMAGE[file_name|width|height]]"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "IMAGE"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "file_name|width|height"
}
```

Comment: +1  as it will scale for multiple instances in the same string

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't use `preg_match`, but works just as well.

```
$var = '[$IMAGE[file_name|width|height]]';
$p1 = explode('[',$var);
$tag = str_replace('$','',$p1[1]);
$param = str_replace(']','',$p1[2]);

echo $tag.'<br />';
echo $param;
```

Comment: +1 for workable string operations. Suggest using the 3rd param to `explode()` to limit to 2 components `$p1 = explode('[', $var, 2);`

Comment: thanks @Michael - I tried adding that third param and the var_dump gave me a string[0] of "", and string[1] of the full string?

Comment: @Michael ah - got it, needs to be 3 not 2, as the first item in the array is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '[$IMAGE[file_name|width|height]]';
preg_match("/\[\\$(.*)\[(.*)\]\]/",$string,$matches);

$tag = $matches[1];  
$param = $matches[2];

echo "TAG: " . $tag;
echo "<br />";
echo "PARAM: " . $param;
?>
```

Comment: I would use `([^\]]*)` to avoid greedy results.